# create database if not exists dbname , 1 row affected

Tags: mysql, database

When I try to create a database which already exists,

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why does it show `1 row affected` message second time , even though it is not creating a new database with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;` command won't directly modify rows in an exiting instance of the `test` database, it will affect the actual details stored internally in the `mysql` database, or possibly in one of the derived meta views, like the `information_schema` or `performance_schema` etc.
The reported `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)` is referring to a row in one of these internal data constructs. When you reissue the `CREATE DATABASE` command, and it fails gracefully thanks to the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause, it is still likely to store meta-data internally, maybe an accumulating field that counts warnings or similar, or even just a 'last acted on' timestamp against this database's row. In any case the stored data in this record is changed, and is reflected as an 'affected' row.